# Склоняется ли слово "калигатия"?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, склонение

Встретил слово "калигатия" в книге Ивана Ефремова "Таис Афинская". "Яндекс" и "Гугл" не дали ответ.

Comment: Я просмотрел поиском fb2-файл с этим романом и не нашёл там такого слова. Проверьте, пожалуйста: возможно, в вашем издании опечатка.